# How to subtract two columns in Informix 12.10

Tags: sql, informix

I would like to subtract a column from another column in Informix 12.10.

```
SELECT
    NAME,
    PRICE1
    PRICE2,
    (PRICE1 - PRICE2) AS VALUE
FROM PRODUCTS
```

Does somebody have an idea how can I do that?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Note that there are only 3 values selected by the SQL shown, not 4 as the layout suggests is intended.  Since there is no comma at the end of the line containing just PRICE1, the PRICE2 on the next line is treated as the 'display label' (column alias) for PRICE1.  Adding a comma after the first PRICE1 would display the two raw prices and the difference.  Using the explicit AS clause should suspend any keyword meaning for VALUE — Informix takes a permissive attitude towards using keywords as identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VALUE` is a keyword in IBM Informix SQL.  Use something else for the alias, or, if you must use `VALUE`, then wrap it in double quotes.

```sql
SELECT
    NAME,
    PRICE1
    PRICE2,
    (PRICE1 - PRICE2) AS "VALUE"
FROM PRODUCTS;
```

Comment: I changed it to the original post.